# What is hierarchy for these grammars: LL1,SLR1,LR0,LR1 and LALR1?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

How are these grammars related to each other? e.g. SLR is a subset of LALR1. Is there any set methods for working out the relationships between the others?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three types of Context Free Grammers(CFG'S).

1)Floyd-Evans Parsable
2)Unambiguous CFGs
3)Operator Precedence

All the ones u have mentioned above are Unambiguous CFG'S.

LL(0) < LL(1) < LL(k). LR(0) < SLR(1) < LALR(1) < LR(1) < LR(k).
Also, LL(k) < LR(k)

**Every LR(0) grammer id SLR(1) and every SLR(1) is LALR(1) which in turn is LR(1).**

Comment: Nice answer. Is LL(1) < LALR(1)? If yes, then is LL(1) < SLR(1) too?

Comment: Answer to comment above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487588/example-for-ll1-grammer-which-is-not-lalr/6492798#6492798