# Example for LL(1) Grammar which is NOT LALR?

Tags: parsing, compilation

I am learning now about parsers on my Theory Of Compilation course. 
I need to find an example for grammar which is in LL(1) but not in LALR. 
I know it should be exist. please help me think of the most simple example to this problem.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a trick question, or possibly you have it reversed. I was under the impression (from my compilers course last semester) that LL(1) was a subset of LALR, and thus, all LL(1) grammars are LALR. I could be misremembering, let me dig out my dragon book.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Some googling](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22ll%281%29%20but%20not%20lalr%22) brings up this example for a non-LALR(1) grammar, which is LL(1):

```
S ::= '(' X 
    | E ']' 
    | F ')'
X ::= E ')' 
    | F ']'
E ::= A
F ::= A
A ::= ε
```

The LALR(1) construction fails, because there is a reduce-reduce conflict between E and F. In the set of LR(0) states, there is a state made up of

```
E ::= A . ;
F ::= A . ;
```

which is needed for both S and X contexts. The LALR(1) lookahead sets for these items thus mix up tokens originating from the S and X productions. This is different for LR(1), where there are different states for these cases.

With LL(1), decisions are made by looking at FIRST sets of the alternatives, where ')' and ']' always occur in different alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

From the Dragon book (Second Edition, p. 242):

> The class of grammars that can be parsed using LR methods is a proper superset of the class of grammars that can be parsed with predictive or LL methods. For a grammar to be LR(k), we must be able to recognize the occurrence of the right side of a production in a right-sentential form, with k input symbols of lookahead. This requirement is far less stringent than that for LL(k) grammars where we must be able to recognize the use of a production seeing only the first k symbols of what the right side derives. Thus, it should not be surprising that LR grammars can describe more languages than LL grammars.

Comment: Second, this answer does not contradicts the assumption that there is a grammar in LL(1) which is not in LALR. that is because as you may know, LALR < LR(1). in the lectures slides that we learn from, there is a schematic picture of relations between the grammar classes, and it can be seen very easily that LALR does not contain LL(1). they indeed have a big intersection but one does not contain an other. look at page 7 of the following lecture: http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/%7Eyahave/courses/tocs2011/compilers-lec04.pdf and see what I mean.

Comment: Ah, that's right. As Gunther points out in his answer, LALR loses some generality from CLR because it mixes states.